# how to invoque var function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to use this js code, and I'm not able to understand it, and how to use it.

```
var ctrlStageAsocDocumentsEvent = (function()
{
    var module = {};
    var self = module;

    module.openPopup = function(configDoc)
    {
        var timestamp = (new Date).getTime();

        popupC = window.open('www.google.es','', 'titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,resizable=no, top=0, left=0, type=fullWindow,fullscreen,scrollbars=yes');
    };


    module.init = function(param)
    {
        alert("hello");

    };

    return {
        init: module.init
    };
})();
```

From Chrome console I tried `ctrlStageAsocDocumentsEvent` and it only have init, how can I access to openpopup?

I supposed `ctrlStageAsocDocumentsEvent.openPopup();` but this doesnt work

Comment: p.s. Invoque === invoke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a public variable like:

```
return {
   init: module.init,
   openPopup: module.openPopup
};
```

and then you can access it like:

```
ctrlStageAsocDocumentsEvent.openPopup();
```